# Determinant of matrix with orthogonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, determinant

If I have $n$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional coordinate space such that the vectors form an orthogonal set (i.e. they are linearly independent).

And I make a matrix $A$ such that each row is one of those vectors, will the determinant be $\pm$ the product of the norms of the vectors?

If so how could I prove it?

Comment: What about the $\det (AA^T)$?

Comment: So unless I am mistaken that would be a diagonal matrix with entries equal to the square of the norms of $A$. If it is true that the product of matrices yields the product of the determinants then we get the result we want for A, right?.

Comment: Yes using also that $\det A = \det A^T$.

Comment: "the vectors form an orthogonal set (i.e. they are linearly independent)" -- these statements are not equivalent: the two vectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are linearly independent but not orthogonal.

Comment: my use off the latin acornym might be a little abusive here by i.e. I meant the first implies the second, not equivalence.

Comment: You can use subsection  "Geometric meaning"  from this wikipedia note https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant